# How to implement a cron job for multiple sessions each with their own intervals

Tags: java, spring, cron

I want to utilize a spring cron annotation to run a particular service every minute within a certain interval in three different session per day.

For example:
First session: 8:15am - 12:36pm,
Second session: 12:40pm - 3:11pm,
Third session: 3:20pm - 4:35pm.

How do I set the cron expression for this particular example?

I have checked for this on the Oracle documentation and this is the closest implementation I have come across

"0 0/5 14,18 * * ?    Fire every 5 minutes starting at 2:00 PM and ending at 2:55 PM, AND fire every 5 minutes starting at 6:00 PM and ending at 6:55 PM, every day"

There is no instance on intervals between different hours and different sessions

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 29-35 11,12 * * ?")
 public static void testCron() {
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = new Date(); 
   System.out.println("testing cron per minute " + dateFormat.format(date)); }
```

From the test code above, it prints the comment between 11:29 and 11:35 but nothing past 11:35. The next printout is from 12:29, and so on.

Comment: `@Scheduled` doend't work in `static` methods, need to be regular methods. Just add multiple `@Scheduled` annotations.

Comment: This implementation worked. Thank you for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish that you can annotate your method with multiples `@Scheduled` annotations, also improving the readibility and pourpouse of the agenda.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15-36 8-12 * * ?")
@Scheduled(cron = "0 40-11 12-15 * * ?")
@Scheduled(cron = "0 20-35 15-16 * * ?")
 public static void testCron() {
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = new Date(); 
   System.out.println("testing cron per minute " + dateFormat.format(date)); }
```

You may be interested in test some crontab configurations using the [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru) online tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 1-2 * * * *", fixedRate = 5000)
```

The method with this expression runs from 01:00 to 02:00 each 5 minutes. Modify this expression and use it on two diferent methods. Each one should call to your testCron method